How can I add link to admin page drupal for a specific roles
I try to add a link appear in /admin for a specific role. This specific role has a few permissions (adding specific content for example) and I would like to hide certain links appear in /admin and to add other links in this same page.
I tried to use the hook MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter but I did not find the way to add links into this.
What solution for this ?
Thanks

use the yourmodule.routing.yml file to define a route, FYI "admin-routes" are not defined by having /admin in their routename, in example /node/add ;-)
